# How to check if list is a list of integers

Tags: python

I have a list and I need to be sure that there are no strings only integers.
I'm trying to use `if isinstance(a, int):` but seems like it doesn't work with lists

```
a = [3, 5, 65, 15, 10, 7, "one"] 
if isinstance(a, int): //should be False
   pass
```

Comment: `if all(isinstance(i, int), for i in a):`

Comment: Alternative to `isinstance`: `all(n.__class__.__name__ == 'int' for n in a)`

Comment: @mathfux Using Python dunder methods is [discouraged](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

Comment: @mathfux furthermore, that is far from the idiomatic way to check the type of an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
all(isinstance(n, int) for n in a)  # False for your example
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `all`:

```
if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in a):
```